# shadow effect on each button group's button

Tags: css, extjs, shadow

I am having one button group in which I am having two buttons.
  Now when I select one button that button should have some shadow effect which will show viewer that button is being pressed and other button should be seen as unpressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 <div class="buttonSet">
         <a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a>
         <a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .buttonSet { padding:20px;}
  a.button{ 
         padding:5px 10px; 
         border:solid 1px #cccccc; 
         background:#efefef;
         font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333333;
         text-decoration:none;
 }
 a.button:active {
     color:#000000;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
```

[**DEMOM**](http://jsfiddle.net/74eEn/)

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple way

```
     .youButton:active{
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is possible if you use a link to style your buttons:

```
/*HTML*/
<a href="#" class="button">Click Me</a>

/*CSS*/
a.button:active{
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

The *Active* selector will change the style of your link when it is in its pressed state. But if you are looking to use real html *Buttons* I don't know of an easy way to fix that.

You can take a look at this tutorial: [Pressed Button State With CSS](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/12/16/pressed-button-state-with-css/)